# Is int* number_1 same as int *number_1?

Tags: c, pointers

I am little confused about how pointers are/or can be used.
for example:

```
int addtwonumbersfunction(int* number_1, int* number_2)
```

Is it same as: `int addtwonumbersfunction(int *number_1, int *number_2)`?

Does it matter where * is placed? after int, or before variable?

Comment: You can write it without spaces or with as many spaces as you want.

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176260/what-is-the-convention-for-the-star-location-in-reference-variables

Answer (score 2):

> Does it matter where * is placed? after int, or before variable?

No it does not matter.  Your two examples are semantically the same.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, you can write both. `int` is the main type, so on multiple variable declaration, you'd have to add `*` everytime. Some prefer `int* var` because of grouping type & variable name, others like `int *var` because of the behaviour i described with multiple declaration.

Comment: Visually binding the `*` complicates maintenance due to how humans recognise patterns.